# Environment variables readable by Apache/PHP and Systemd/node

Tags: php, node.js, linux, apache, systemd

On the same server, I have a apache php application and a nodejs application (started via systemd).

For systemd/node, I put the following config:

```
[Service]
EnvironmentFile=/etc/environment
```

For apache, I have put the following line in `/etc/apache2/envvars`

```
. /etc/environment
```

My problem is:

- It works in PHP and standalone node if I put `export` before each variable, but not in node via systemd
- It works in node via systemd if I remove the `export`

Is there a way for me to write these variables in a single place that can be used by Apache/PHP and node started via systemd ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the export statement version of your environent file if you change your `ExecStart=` line to something like: `ExecStart=/bin/sh -c ". /etc/environment && exec /PATH/TO/NODEJS/APPLICATION"`. This is kludgy though.